# What is wrong with the escaped newline in this sed command?

Tags: sed

I am trying to add the line `text += num.toString(16);` after each line, using sed.

My approach is: `Replace every new line with a new line, plus text += num.toString(16);`. That is:

```
sed 's/\
/\
text \+= num\.toString\(16\);/g'
```

But I couldn't get this working. I am getting `unterminated substitute pattern` from sed.

What is wrong here?

I am using BSD sed.

Comment: Does a simple `sed -e 's/$/ text += num.toString(16);/g'` work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use:

```
s/\
/
```

to match newline in pattern space in `s/pattern/replacement/` form. It depends on implementations to interpret that pattern. Both GNU sed and BSD sed treats it as literal newline, but BSD sed [doesn't accept](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/386ddae58459341ec567604707805814a2128a57/usr.bin/sed/compile.c#L376) and [will raise the error](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/386ddae58459341ec567604707805814a2128a57/usr.bin/sed/compile.c#L323).

Generally, you can't match a newline at the end of input line, but you can use `\n` to match newline appears in pattern space as the result of `N` command.

The right way, POSIXLY:

```
sed 'a\
text += num.toString(16);
'
```

or:

```
sed 's/$/\
text += num.toString(16);/'
```

Comment: A newline cannot be used in the pattern space but it can be used in the replacement space, right?

Comment: @Utku: yes, and must be preceded by a backslash for portability.

Answer (score 0):

The same applicable through `awk` as following:

```
awk '{print $0"\ntext += num.toString(16);"}' file
```

In this case `awk` will print each line as is, then will print `text += num.toString(16);` in a new line.